# TypeScript clone self instance with self Class Type

Tags: typescript, polymorphism, clone

I want to clone the current class instance and create inside `clone()` an instance of a polymorphic class, something like this:

```
class State
{
    public clone():State
    {
        const state = new State();
        this._copyData(state);
        return state;
    }

    protected _copyData(target:this):void
    {
    }
}

class StateExtends extends State
{
    public clone():StateExtends
    {
        const state = new StateExtends();
        return state;
    }

    protected _copyData(target:this):void
    {
        super._copyData(target);
    }
}
```

When overriding the State class I want the `clone()` signature to stay the same in all classes hierarchy. Can I do something like this:

```
class State
{
    public clone():this
    {
        const state = new this();
        this._copyData(state);
        return state;
    }

    protected _copyData(target:this):void
    {
    }
}

class StateExtends extends State
{
    protected _copyData(target:this):void
    {
        super._copyData(target);
    }
}
```

But this is not working.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

At runtime `this` is just an instance of the class, not the class constructor, so you can't call `new this()`.  But you can access the `constructor` property of `this` and call `new this.constructor()`.

There's a little wrinkle; that won't compile since by default, TypeScript considers the `constructor` object property to be `Function`.  Which isn't `new`able.  There are [reasons](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841) for this.

To get `new this.constructor()` to compile without warning, you either need to assert the type like `new (this.constructor as any)()`, or add a `constructor` property to `State` with the right signature:

```
class State
{
    "constructor": new() => this; // no-arg polymorphic constructor

    public clone():this
    {
        const state = new this.constructor(); // okay
        this._copyData(state);
        return state;
    }

    // etc
}
```

That should hopefully work for you.  Good luck!

Comment: thanks. the `"constructor": new() => this;` is not needed. it compile without it. TypeScript v2.6.2